# Solve in non-negative integers the equation $6^n+7=m^{k+2}$

Tags: number-theory, integers

> Solve in non-negative integers the equation 
>   $$6^n+7=m^{k+2}$$

I  found $n=0, m=2, k=1$. I don't know if there are any other solutions

Comment: For $1\le n\le 10^4$, $6^n+7$ is not a perfect power, so probably there are no more solutions.

Comment: $k$ has to be odd since $3$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{5}$. Apart from that, we have something similar to Catalan's conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture), and cyclotomic polynomials should be the key (by writing $6^n+6 = (m-1)(m^{k+1}+\ldots+1)$)

Comment: One can solve this using linear forms in logarithms to bound $k$ and then applying local arguments to rule out small values of the exponents. There might be an easy way to tackle this equation, but I don't see it off hand.